# Jpa (Hibernate) OneToOne Bidirectional Save Child Merge 2 Side FK's

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using spring boot 2, jdk 8 with hibernate. I am not using cascade. On client side sending id for reference entity and jpa merging fk. I have no problem onetomany-manytoone, manytoone or many-to-many relesional mappings. On-to-one i cant do that. For example;

```
public class Child extends AbstractEntity {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;

}

public class Child extends AbstractEntity {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Child child;
}
```

Using srping data JpaRepository.

```
childService.save(child) //Child has parent reference with id;
```

DB Result
child table everthing is okey. parent_id merged.
parent table child_id NULL not merged.

I try mappeyBy, joinColumn, CascadeType.Merge doesnt work. If i save child after save parent its ok. But i want to when i save child with parent id. Parent table merge child id too. Can i do that?

Comment: what do you want exactly? do you want save parent id (pk) to child table as pk or fk?

Comment: I want to when i save child merge parent_id to child table(this is work) also merge child_id to parent table(this not work alllways null child_id).

Comment: In a @OneToOne relationship, I could suggest use parent table pk_id same in child table.